# Python script for finding 302 redirects?

Tags: python, redirect, web-crawler, http-status-code-302

So I am using https://github.com/bartdag/pylinkvalidator, seems like a great tool for finding 404 on the page. But the website I am crawling has the 404's redirected to a pretty `sorry for 404` page. so the crawler script is not detecting the original link 404's.

I wrote a small script that print logs the original link, 302, and destination link, but that takes the link individually, I need to crawl the whole website like the `pylinkvalidator`.

this script does the link individually but needs to crawl the whole website

```py
import requests
link = 'https://example.com/1234sdsd'
r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=False)
print(link,r.status_code, r.headers['Location'])
```

Even other tools are fine like selenium, but I think it will have the same issue.

Comment: At the end of pylinkvalidator README is code usage example, did you try with something like `[page for page in crawled_sites.error_pages if page.is_redirect]`?

Comment: @ipaleka where did you see that? i dont see it

Comment: That line is mine, I peeked the code and that example usage code.